# for loop in c from scanf

Tags: c, input, io

I am attempting to solve a programming exercice on the CodeChef platform in C, but I'm having trouble reading the input...

Here what I am supposed to read:

```
2
3
1 4
2 1
0 1
0 1
2
1 3
0 2
1 0
```

Here is the [link](https://www.codechef.com/problems/KCHESS) to the exercise for more details, but in summary, the first line contains a single integer N, the second line is a integer T, the following T lines all contain 2 space-separated integers X Y, followed by a last line of space separated integers. N is the number of blocks starting by a integer for T.

Here the code that I wrote in order to read this data:

```
int main(void) {
  int T, N, i, j, x, y;
  scanf("%d", &T);
  for (i=0; i>T; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &N);
    // ....
    for (j=0; j>N; j++) {
      scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
      // ....
    }
    scanf("%d %d",&x, &y);
    // ....
  }
}
```

What seems to be happening is the code seems to be only reading the `N` variable after which the program just exits normally... I've been staring at this for hours and I feel lost, I can't seem to figure out what's going on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Typo: `j>N` should be `j<N`

Comment: And `i>T` should be `i<T`. This is a common C idiom in `for` loops, you should get used to it.

Comment: Note: running your code in a debugger line by line is an invaluable way to see what’s happening. You can monitor the variables and see what’s happening and determine why

Comment: Note that in general you should check that your `scanf()` calls return `1` or `2`, depending on the number of variables you attempt to read.